# What is an adjective that can be used to describe someone who doesn't keep promises or goes back on what they said previously?

Tags: single-word-requests

I mean a person who has said he/she was gonna do something and then didn't. Would it be something like dishonorable?

Answer (score 1):

At best, **unreliable**.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unreliable):

> 1. not reliable; not to be relied or depended on.

There are plenty of nastier things such people are called.

Answer (score 1):

fickle - marked by lack of steadfastness, constancy, or stability : given to erratic changeableness. (www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fickle)

Answer (score 1):

To go back on a promise is to "renege" (ri-negg). I don't think there's a noun from this.

Note: A derogatory, racist expression for someone who gives something then takes it back is "Indian giver".  (Don't use this phrase, but you might encounter it in literature.)

Comment: And one must be careful using the term "reneger", as it could be taken the wrong way.